# section & article tags

Tags: html

I have a very simple question, which one is semantically correct to do :

- have `article` tags inside `section` tags ?
- have `section` tags inside `article` tags ?

I would appreciate all opinions on this, as I googled it and I had all kinds of search result (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/section)

The HTML Section Element (`<section>`) represents a generic section of a document, i.e., a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.

See [**Permitted parent elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/section) in [**Usage context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/section)

### [Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/article)

The HTML Article Element (`<article>`) represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g., in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

See [**Permitted parent elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/article) in [**Usage context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/article)

[**Which one to choose?**](http://oli.jp/2009/html5-structure1/)

> To think about HTML4, we can compare this to `<p>` and `<blockquote>`. Both are block-level elements for text, but `<blockquote>` is like a subset of `<p>`, with a more specific meaning (‘this is a block of quoted text’). The same with `<section>` and `<article>`; `<section>` means related content, but `<article>` means one piece of related content which makes sense on it’s own, even outside the context of the page (the page’s header and footer etc).
>
> The potentially confusing part of this is that `<section>` can be used for parts of a page (e.g. the main content column, the news section on a homepage) and contain `<article>`s, and also for sections of a long `<article>` (i.e. inside an `<article>`).

See [**this article**](http://oli.jp/2009/html5-structure1/) for more clearance.

Comment: Lots of links in your question, I likey! +1.